# How do I hold a package in landscape?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, landscape

I have a [held package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) in Ubuntu, and Landscape recognizes it -- this is great.  But how do I hold a new package from the Landscape UI?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common question, and the UI is a bit tricky.  I took some screenshots.

First:

- **Computers** -> Select Computers -> **Packages** -> Find Package to Hold

You should end up on a screen like this:

[image: packages]

Expand the row of the package you want to hold:

[image: Expanded Row]

Click the little package icon:

[image: Ready to Apply Changes]

Then apply changes to generate the activity that will be sent to the selected computer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click the package icon in a search results page to set/unset a hold on that package. There are also some interesting details about holding kernel updates, with the kernel metapackage playing a key role.

See [Mastering Package Holds](https://f2.svbtle.com/mastering-package-holds) for coverage of this functionality from both Landscape and the shell.